# Any "inherent" definition of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ independent of any matrix representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\SU(2)$ is explained in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(2)).

However, if I know right, this definition itself is known the "fundamental representation".

I wonder if there is any "inherent" definition of $\SU(2)$ **independent of** any matrix representation.

In the case of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, the structure constant $\epsilon_{ijk}$ seems to chracterize it without resort to matrix representation. So, I guess the same is possible for $\SU(2)$?

Comment: Yes (of course, it will be only be definition "up to isomorphism"). For instance, it is characterized as: (a) the only Lie group that is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere (b) the only 3-dimensional simply connected Lie group that is compact and simple ["simple" in the sense of Lie groups: the only closed proper subgroups are central]. Note that behind each such a definition, there is some proof that this indeed characterizes $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Comment: Let $V$ be a $2$-dimensional complex vector space equipped with a (positive-definite) complex inner product. The group of endomorphisms which preserve the inner product (i.e. are unitary) and have determinant $1$ is a Lie group which is isomorphic to $SU(2)$. Does this count?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese oh yes. Your answer seems plausible. It doesn't seem difficult to show that such definition is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: Using the real Lie algebra to construct the Lie group is also an option.

Comment: @WillSawin Could you tell me how? You mean by using the exponential map?

Comment: Yes, because two simply-connected Lie groups with isomorphic Lie algebras are isomorphic, so we can definite it as the unique simply connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}_2$.

Comment: One nice definition that does not explicitly use matrices is as the unit sphere of quaternions

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462853/any-inherent-definition-of-mathrmsu2-independent-of-any-matrix-represen#comment1201455_462853), I think your definition of "simple" is too permissive: it allows non-trivial tori.

Comment: @WillSawin, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1201520), as you of course know, this is a matrix representation, though it's not the usual one: the adjoint action of $\operatorname{SU}_2$ on $\mathfrak{su}_2$ is one (the best?) way to realise it as a double cover of $\operatorname{SO}_3$.  (On the other hand, MichaelAlbanese's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1201461) is even more explicitly a matrix representation, and is [acceptable](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1201463), so I guess I don't understand the question.)

Comment: @LSpice yes: I should have said "nonabelian" (but anyway my characterization was correct because 3-tori are not simply connected). Actually "3-dimensional compact simply connected Lie group" would have been enough.

Comment: @LSpice The construction of a Lie group with a given Lie algebra via the exponential map and the universal cover can be done with any faithful representation, not just the adjoint representation. Because of this I think it's fair to say it doesn't use any specific matrix representation.